# File disappeared on move

Tags: command-line, files, mv

I had a directory with a file and another empty directory in it like this:

```
.
..
file.ext
folder
```

I did:

```
mv file.ext /folder
```

The file disappeared now, not in folder too not where it was before!

Anyway to find it back?

Thanks

Comment: Were you working as root? if so, you *probably* just renamed `file.ext` to `/folder` (which would be a file in the filesystem root directory `/`): look there.

Comment: yes its there, now how to retrieve it? :) ??

Comment: it doesn't matter if you are working as root or not, because there was a / in front of the folder name, it will go to / which is the root of your file system.

Comment: no mchid, it wouldn't go there, it would become that

steeldriver is right, it became the file with name folder

Comment: steeldriver please write it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct

Comment: @nabtron yes it would go there because that is the path

Comment: well i just checked and it was a file with name "folder" in /

Comment: can you please explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the directory `/folder` (under root directory, `/`) does not exist, and if you were working as `root`, you have renamed (moved) the file `file.txt` as `folder` under `/`.

Doing a `ls -l /folder` should show you the file.

Another point is, if a directory `/folder` does exist, then look under that directory for the file i.e. `/folder/file.txt`.

Also note that if you append a `/` to the destination path, you would get a different message like:

```
mv: cannot move ‘file.txt’ to ‘/destination/’: Not a directory
```

and the file will not be renamed.

For example:

```
% sudo mv file.txt /spamegg/
mv: cannot move ‘file.txt’ to ‘/spamegg/’: Not a directory

% sudo mv file.txt /spamegg 

% ls /spamegg  
/spamegg
```

Comment: I have a question, if I move the file somewhere other than / like at /folder/folder2/folder3 it doesn't become folder3, rather it creates a new folder3 if it doesn't exist already and then sits there? or will it do the same and become a file folder3 there too?

Comment: @nabtron the rule is universal..if a directory exists the file will be copied into it and if the directory does not exist it will be named as the "directory" i.e. last component..

Comment: Unless you also *end* the path with a slash, eg `/folder/folder2/folder3/`... If that doesn't exist you'll see a `mv: failed to access ‘...’: Not a directory`

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to move the file to the folder in the same directory, you should have done this:

```
mv file.ext folder
```

However, because you have done this instead:

```
mv file.ext /folder
```

the file has been moved and renamed to `/folder` instead of `folder/file.ext`

.

Run the following command:

```
cd /
```

and then run:

```
ls | grep folder
```

and it should show up in the results.

Comment: no it wouldn't go in that folder, it would become a file named folder in / folder

Comment: @nabtron only if the directory of that name did or does not exist would that happen

Comment: @nabtron and then, it would become a file named folder in /

Comment: does it happen for root only or for all?

Comment: @nabtron when working as any user

Comment: no i mean for root main directory or for any subdirectory too?

Comment: @nabtron Yes, you are right for all directories. My answer assumed there was a directory named folder in / already but since there was not I guess the file was renamed /folder.

Comment: yap! i appreciate your help!