# Accidentally made a file disappear using mv. Where should I look for it?

Tags: command-line, files, filesystem, hidden-files

I had a file in which I had some credentials; and for some reason, it's hidden now. I can see on my desktop that there are two folders with **.** and **..** name. Where did they come from? My file was `sample.txt`. I messed up with the mv command, and the file became hidden. Now, I'm trying to figure out where my file is.

I need some help!

Edit: These are the commands I used:

```
1861  mv sample.txt Downloads
1872  find sample.txt
1887  mv .. sample.txt
1888  mv ... sample.txt
```

Comment: I've no idea where your file is, but does this answer your question? [What do "." and ".." mean when in a folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54900/what-do-and-mean-when-in-a-folder)

Comment: `.` refers to current directory and `..` refers to the parent directory. There's nothing like hidden file in Ubuntu. Hidden files just have their name starting with `.`, for example, `.sample`. Did you run any command to move the file?

Comment: If you press the up arrow in Terminal it will show your command history. Can you try that and find the exact command(s) you ran before the file disappeared, and edit them in to the question please? This will reveal the file paths you used.

Comment: I have edited my question with the commands that I used. @TomBrossman

Comment: This question is not Duplicate... I edited the title and it's obviously clear that it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Very closely related: [File disappeared on move](https://askubuntu.com/q/698480) That's the (apparently quite common) case where an [absolute path](https://foldoc.org/absolute+path) to a nonexistent file in `/` is accidentally used as a target of `mv` run with `sudo`. In this question, a [relative path](https://foldoc.org/relative+path) to a nonexistent file in the current directory was accidentally used a target of `mv` (without `sudo`). That affects how answers are worded, but the principle is the same. The other differences are even more minor. This might be considered a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that the behavior of commands like `mv source target`, when `target` does not end with a `/`, depends on whether there is an existing directory (or an existing symbolic link that points to a directory) called `target`. Sometimes that makes them do a different thing than what you expect.

You showed four commands. The first command is the important one:

```
mv sample.txt Downloads
```

That command moved or renamed `sample.txt`.

If there was nothing called `sample.txt` in the current directory in the first place, then `mv sample.txt Downloads` failed and no change was made. But based on your description, it sounds like there *was* such a file. So:

1. If there was a directory called `Downloads` in the current directory, then `mv sample.txt Downloads` tried **to move `sample.txt` into the directory called `Downloads`**, and probably succeeded. This also happens if `Downloads` is a symbolic link to a directory rather than an actual directory.
2. If there was no directory called `Downloads` in the current directory, then `mv sample.txt Downloads` tried **to rename `sample.txt` to be called `Downloads`**. (Not `Downloads.txt`, just `Downloads`.)

If this was in a `Desktop` directory, the second scenario is probably what occurred, since you probably don't have a `Downloads` directory *in* a `Desktop` directory. But if you do, you're in the first scenario.

So you should look inside the directory you were in when you ran `mv sample.txt Downloads` for an entry called `Downloads`. Depending on what existed before, this should either *be* the file formerly known as `sample.txt`, or it should *contain* `sample.txt`.

---

As for the other three commands you showed, they should've made no changes at all, and they also should not be expected to have revealed any useful information about the effect of the first command.

`find sample.txt` won't show anything unless there's something called `sample.txt` residing *directly* in the current directory. If you want to find files contained anywhere, directly or indirectly, in the current directory, whose names are `sample.txt`, you would use `find . -name sample.txt`. (Of course, that won't find a file whose name is no longer `sample.txt`.)

In `mv .. sample.txt`, `..` is a name for the parent directory, which is the directory that the current directory resides in, or if the current directory is `/`, then the parent directory is `/` itself. Every directory has a `..` entry with this meaning. That command tries to rename the `..` entry for the parent directory to be called `sample.txt`. This should simply fail with an error, which in this case will somewhat confusingly be reported as "Device or resource busy".

In `mv ... sample.txt`, `...` is not treated specially. Directories always contain the special entries `.` and `..`, but the name `...` is not special. So you probably didn't have a file called `...`.

- Assuming you didn't, that command failed and made no changes.
- If you did have a file called `...` in the current directory, and no *directory* called `sample.txt` (and no symbolic link called `sample.txt` that points to a directory), then `...` would be renamed to `sample.txt`. If `sample.txt` already existed and was neither a directory nor a symbolic link to a directory, *it would be replaced* and (unless there are other hard links to it) it could be difficult or impossible to recover depending on how much the filesystem has subsequently been written. However, this is unlikely, since you probably never had a file called `...`, and since that command was run *after* a command that probably succeeded either at renaming `sample.txt` in place or putting it somewhere else, and since you don't currently see a file called `sample.txt` in the directory where you ran the commands.
- In the unlikely event that you had both an entry in the current directory called `...` and another entry `sample.txt` that was a directory or a symbolic link to a directory, `mv ... sample.txt` would try to move `...` into the `sample.txt` directory (or into the directory targeted by the symbolic link).

Comment: Woah! I just didn't notice that my `sample.txt` was renamed to `Downloads` on my Desktop. Thanks for the useful info. I'll keep all this in mind the next time I try to move files to another directory.

Comment: Nice answer... :)